# what does *-*-c-*-*-* mean in a font-setting

Tags: x11, fonts

I often see Fonts being set like this: (e.g. in dmenu or bar-ain't-recursive)

```
-*-terminus-medium-r-normal-*-14-*-*-*-c-*-*-*
```

what does these `*-c*-*` sign mean? I really don't get it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a font name that follow the [XLFD](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/XLFD/xlfd.html#fontname) convention.

The `*` are wildcards, the different elements are separated by `-`.

From the convention page, here we have :

> - FAMILY_NAME : a string that identifies the range or family of typeface designs that are all variations of one basic typographic style. Here : "terminus".
> - WEIGHT_NAME : a string that identifies the font's typographic weight, that is, the nominal blackness of the font. Here "medium".
> - SLANT field : a code-string that indicates the overall posture of the typeface design used in the font. Here : r "Roman Upright design"
> - SETWIDTH_NAME : the font's typographic proportionate width. Here : "normal".
> - PIXEL_SIZE : the body size of the font at a particular POINT_SIZE and RESOLUTION_Y. Here "14".

And the "c" is for "charcell":

> - SPACING : a code-string that indicates the escapement class of the font, that is, monospace (fixed pitch), proportional (variable pitch), or charcell (a special monospaced font that conforms to the traditional data-processing character cell font model).

The rest is not specified (replaced with wildcards).